# UPDATE one table using another

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sql-update

I've buit a database in which there are these tables:

```
companies (a,b,nazov,ic_dph,mesto,ulica_cislo,psc) 
finan (nazov,ic_dph,mesto,ulica_cislo,psc)
```

In table `companies`, the columns ic_dph,mesto,ulica and psc are empty. I want to update those columns with columns from `finan` table. I've tried many **SQLite3** queries but none of them worked.

USING UPDATE:

```
UPDATE companies SET companies.ic_dph = finan.ic_dph, companies.mesto = finan.mesto, companies.ulica_cislo = finan.ulica_cislo, companies.psc=finan.psc WHERE companies.nazov = finan.nazov
```

USING JOIN:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS (SELECT * FROM companies JOIN finan)
```

Both queries returns some syntax errors.

Could you give me an advice what's wrong?

Comment: @KevinTinnemans Could you elaborate it a little? On this example? I've tried to put INNER before JOIN and the same problem is still happening.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to replace all the values, probably the best way is to delete rows and insert new values:

```
create temporary table t as 
    select c.a, c.b, c.nazov, f.ic_dph, f.mesto, f.ulica, f.psc 
    from companies c left join
         finan f
         on c.nazov = f.nazov;

delete from companies;

insert into companies(a, b, nazov, ic_dph, mesto, ulica, psc)
    select a, b, nazov, ic_dph, mesto, ulica, psc
    from t;
```

Do be careful using this method.

Another method is a bunch of correlated subqueries.  First, be sure you have an index on `finan(nazov)`.  Then:

```
update companies c
    set ic_dph = (select ic_ph from finan f where f.nazov = c.nazov),
        mesto = (select mesto from finan f where f.nazov = c.nazov),
        ulica = (select ulica from finan f where f.nazov = c.nazov),
        psc = (select psc from finan f where f.nazov = c.nazov)
    where exists (select 1 from finan f where f.nazov = c.nazov);
```

Comment: SQLite has no TRUNCATE; that optimization is transparently done with DELETE.